# Derived class from template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Multiple definitions of `Derived` class is not allowed, so the following is a compile time error.

```
class A1
{    };

class A2
{    };

class Derived: public A1
{    };
class Derived: public A2
{    };
```

Sameways, why isn't the following, a compile time error?
Wouldn't there be 2 versions of `Derived` class, one inheriting from `A1` while the other from `A2`?

```
class A1
{    };

class A2
{    };

template<class T>
class Derived: public T
{    };

int main()
{
        Derived<A1> *ptr1 = new Derived<A1>;
        Derived<A2> *ptr2 = new Derived<A2>;    
}
```

Comment: because `Derived<T>`, varying `T`, are different classes

Comment: But the name of the class remains the same. It isn't mangled. Then how is it allowed?

Comment: @anurag86: the template parameters are part of the type (and they are mangled with the class name in binaries)

Comment: `Derived` isn't a class, is a class template; `Derived<A1> ` and `Derived<A2>` are classes; but different.

Comment: *"the name of the class remains the same"* It's not. You have two different classes: `Derived<A1>` and `Derived<A2>`. `Derived` itself is not a class, it's a class template. *"It isn't mangled."* But it is? `typeid(...).name()` gives me `7DerivedI2A1E` and `7DerivedI2A2E` respectively.

Comment: Yep. Just added few functions in class and called them. and ran `nm out|xargs c++filt|grep Derived` and it showed no `Derived` but `Derived<A1>` and `Derived<A2>` .Thanks all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There would be not two `Derived` classed, inherited from `A1` and `A2`, but literally one class `Derived<A1>` and `Derived<A2>`. The data you pass to template argument, becomes part of the class. Delcaring `Derived<A1>` and passing `A1` to the template argument `T` you *instantiate* a class template.

I think [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5267/bkafi/index.html) is explained better:

> Template **instantiation** *involves generating* a concrete class or
>   function (instance) for a particular combination of template
>   arguments.

And there would be no `Derived` class at all. As max66 pointed out in comment, `Derived` is not a class, but a class template, which will not be compiled alone, without instantiation.